# PhantomJS Web Driver crashes

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I am working with Automation of Web application using Selenium+PhantomJS and I am facing an issue when trying to execute an JAVA Selenium script.

PhantomJS crashes and I get a popup as shown below can anyone suggest the reason for the same.

Log just before crashes is an mentioned below

```
[INFO  - 2016-05-06T11:30:52.538Z] SessionManagerReqHand - 
_cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
```

and below screen appears can anyone let me know why PhantomJS crashes and I am not quiting the browser and have few more steps to perform and it crashes and terminates.

[image]

Any pointers highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the latest phantom browser version and with correct driver.  I remember some issue with driver update so I had to use fork about 6 months ago not sure if that is still the case.

here is the driver dependency I used
        
            com.codeborne
            phantomjsdriver
            1.2.1
            
                
                    org.seleniumhq.selenium
                    selenium-remote-driver

Comment: I am build by cloning repo and using latest drivers and still I get this error

Comment: Sometime ago, I built a template project,  it has sample web test using phantomjs/chrome driver.   https://github.com/contactanant/web-test-template    see if that helps.